# PayPal with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal

I have the following sample to call PayPal's REST API to make a payment. This works fine but I'd like to use it my new MVC app. I guess it needs to be adapted to make use of the MVC helper methods eg RedirectToAction rather than Server.Transfer etc.

Has anyone already converted this sample to run in an MVC4 Controller Action?

```
// ###Payer
            // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
            // Payment Method
            // as `paypal`
            Payer payr = new Payer();
            payr.payment_method = "paypal";
            Random rndm = new Random();
            var guid = Convert.ToString(rndm.Next(100000));

            string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx?";

            // # Redirect URLS
            RedirectUrls redirUrls = new RedirectUrls();
            redirUrls.cancel_url = baseURI + "guid=" + guid;
            redirUrls.return_url = baseURI + "guid=" + guid;

            // ###Details
            // Let's you specify details of a payment amount.
            Details details = new Details();
            details.tax = "15";
            details.shipping = "10";
            details.subtotal = "75";

            // ###Amount
            // Let's you specify a payment amount.
            Amount amnt = new Amount();
            amnt.currency = "USD";
            // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
            amnt.total = "100";
            amnt.details = details;

            // ###Transaction
            // A transaction defines the contract of a
            // payment - what is the payment for and who
            // is fulfilling it. Transaction is created with
            // a `Payee` and `Amount` types
            List<Transaction> transactionList = new List<Transaction>();
            Transaction tran = new Transaction();
            tran.description = "Transaction description.";
            tran.amount = amnt;
            // The Payment creation API requires a list of
            // Transaction; add the created `Transaction`
            // to a List
            transactionList.Add(tran);

            // ###Payment
            // A Payment Resource; create one using
            // the above types and intent as 'sale'
            pymnt = new Payment();
            pymnt.intent = "sale";
            pymnt.payer = payr;
            pymnt.transactions = transactionList;
            pymnt.redirect_urls = redirUrls;

            try
            {
                // ###AccessToken
                // Retrieve the access token from
                // OAuthTokenCredential by passing in
                // ClientID and ClientSecret
                // It is not mandatory to generate Access Token on a per call basis.
                // Typically the access token can be generated once and
                // reused within the expiry window
                string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties()["ClientID"], ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties()["ClientSecret"]).GetAccessToken();

                // ### Api Context
                // Pass in a `ApiContext` object to authenticate 
                // the call and to send a unique request id 
                // (that ensures idempotency). The SDK generates
                // a request id if you do not pass one explicitly. 
                APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
                // Use this variant if you want to pass in a request id  
                // that is meaningful in your application, ideally 
                // a order id.
                // String requestId = Long.toString(System.nanoTime();
                // APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken, requestId ));

                // Create a payment by posting to the APIService
                // using a valid AccessToken
                // The return object contains the status;
                Payment createdPayment = pymnt.Create(apiContext);

                CurrContext.Items.Add("ResponseJson", JObject.Parse(createdPayment.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Formatting.Indented));

                var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();

                while (links.MoveNext())
                {
                    Links lnk = links.Current;
                    if (lnk.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
                    {
                        CurrContext.Items.Add("RedirectURL", lnk.href);
                    }
                }
                Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
            }
            catch (PayPal.Exception.PayPalException ex)
            {
                CurrContext.Items.Add("Error", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        CurrContext.Items.Add("RequestJson", JObject.Parse(pymnt.ConvertToJson()).ToString(Formatting.Indented));

        Server.Transfer("~/Response.aspx");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you need, I actually just finished putting together a basic MVC implementation which supports Authorize, Capture, and Void for PayPal payments (non-credit card) via the REST API.

https://github.com/lakario/PayPalRESTSample

Comment: You should use appropriate word while cancellation:p brilliant example though +1

Comment: Yes... I'm sure most of your clients would not be probing through source code but, you should still definitely change the cancel page redirect